# Auto-increment NuGet package version

Tags: nuget, visual-studio-2019, c#-8.0

Is there a way to auto-increment the NuGet package version when using "Generate NuGetPackage on Build" in C#/.NET Standard 2.1?

Comment: Build in VS or something like Azure Devops? If you use git to manage the version, you can consider using tool like [GitVersion](https://gitversion.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage/msbuild-task/).

Comment: Hi Jonathan, any update for this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you build and publish the project by a build server, and manage the version by Git, you can try the MSBuild [GitVersion](https://gitversion.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage/msbuild-task/) task. For a similar issue, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49765756/c-net-how-to-generate-and-increase-package-version-automatically-especially).

But if you just want a clean build and publish in local Visual Studio without using Git, then I'm afraid for now there isn't any Visual Studio option or [MSBuild task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-task-reference?view=vs-2019) to support this behavior. You can go to the [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html) to suggest the feature because it's a meaningful idea, but currently it's not available.

Also, as from hints [from Martin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47818235/msbuild-tpack-nuget-package-has-always-the-same-version/47819996#47819996) [and Alexandre](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23754398/how-do-i-auto-increment-the-package-version-number/57433541#57433541), you can add this script into xx.csproj:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <GenerateNuspecDependsOn>$(GenerateNuspecDependsOn);SetPackageVersion</GenerateNuspecDependsOn>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="SetPackageVersion" DependsOnTargets="Build">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <!-- <PackageVersion>$([System.DateTime]::Now.ToString(&quot;yyyy.MM.dd.HHmmss&quot;))</PackageVersion> -->
      <!-- You can customize the format and the rule about how version increases here. -->
      <PackageVersion>$([System.DateTime]::Now.ToString(&quot;1.MM.dd&quot;))</PackageVersion>
    </PropertyGroup>
  </Target>
```

Then when you publish the package today, its version is 1.10.4. Tomorrow for 1.10.5, it works if you don't really need to publish different versions of one package in a day. Also you can customize the script to define your version-increasing rule.

---

If targeting multiple frameworks, see *[Build project with multiple targetframeworks in TFS as a NuGet package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48065516/build-project-with-multiple-targetframeworks-in-tfs-as-nuget-package)*

This works when setting the assembly version to wildcard.

```
<Deterministic>false</Deterministic>
<AssemblyVersion>3.0.*</AssemblyVersion>
```

Answer (score 1):

As of *toDate* with Visual Studio 2019 and .NET 5.0, what LoLance suggested about scripting the increment inside the `.csproj` file still works, and we now can use shell commands directly inside the package definition's PropertyGroup for multiple fields, as shown in the picture below:

[image: Proof of concept]